# Proof of Corona problem for $\mathbb{D}$

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, ideals, gelfand-representation

Denote by $H^\infty$ all analytic and bounded functions on the unit disk $\mathbb{D}:=\{x\in\mathbb{C}:|x|<1\}$. I want to show that $\Delta_0:= \{[f\to f(w)]:w\in\mathbb{D}\}\subseteq\Delta(H^\infty)$ is dense in $\Delta(H^\infty)$ (Gelfand spectrum) if and only if for every $f_1,\dots,f_n\in H^\infty$ with $\inf_{z\in\mathbb{D}}\sum_{k=1}^n |f_k(z)|>0$ there exist $g_1,\dots,g_n\in H^\infty$ with $\sum_{k=1}^n f_k g_k=1$.

$\Longrightarrow$: The existence of such $g_k$'s is equivalent to $1\in I(f_1,\ldots,f_n)$, where $I$ is the smallest ideal that contains all $f_k$'s. This means that $I$ is no proper ideal, i.e. $I=H^\infty$. How can I show this? I know that this is true in the space $C(\mathbb{D})$, since $I$ could otherwise be extended to a maximal ideal $\tilde{I}$ and then there would exist an $x\in \mathbb{D}$ such that $\tilde{I} = \{f\in C(\mathbb{D}):f(x)=0\}$, which contradicts $\inf_{z\in\mathbb{D}}\sum_{k=1}^n |f_k(z)|>0$. But is it possible to extend $I\subseteq H^\infty$ to a proper ideal in $C(\mathbb{D})$?

$\Longleftarrow$: I tried taking a $\phi\in\Delta(H^\infty)\backslash \Delta_0$ and a neighborhood $U$ with $U\cap \Delta_0=\emptyset$ and then tried to characterize $U$ by the neighborhoods in weak-* topologies, but I did not arrive at anything useful.

Comment: Any ideal that contains $1$ is the full space by definition of an ideal ($f \times 1=f \in I$!); The converse is hard and I recommend reading a proof in a textbook as it is definitely not a mse problem (simplest proof afaik is by Wolff and takes a good number of pages in Duren's H^p book, while the original proof takes a chapter I think)

Comment: Sorry, but I don't really understand, what you mean. I know that any ideal with 1 is the full space, since I used that in my argumentation. I want to show that $I$ is not a proper ideal so that I can use the information that it has to contain $1$ for the proof of the statement. And I showed that we know that $I$ is not a proper ideal if we can show that it can be extended to a proper ideal on $C(\mathbb{D})$ if it was a proper ideal on $H^\infty$. So the only implication missing is: $I$ is a proper ideal on $H^\infty$ $\to$ $I$ can be extended to proper ideal on $C(\mathbb{D})$.

Comment: Not sure of the question as $H^{\infty}$ is an algebra so any ideal that contains $1$ is the full algebra

Comment: Again, I want to show that $I$ contains 1 by showing that it is the full space and not a proper ideal...

Comment: I am really confused about what you want to prove; by Montel any finitely generated ideal in $H^{\infty}$ is weakly closed so if the pointwise functionals are weakly star dense, for any $\epsilon >0$ a finitely generated proper ideal is $\epsilon$ separated by a pointwise functional; let $w$ st $|\sum a_kf_k(w)| <  \epsilon$  for all bounded analytic ( hence including constants) $a_k$ where $f_k$ are the finitely many generators of the ideal; in particular choosing $a_k$ to make $a_kf_k(w)=|f_k(w)|$ gives a contradiction with the hypothesis of infimum so $1$ is in the ideal

Comment: And of course conversely if the analytic property above ( infimum positive implies ideal contains $1$) is true, the weak star closure of the pointwise functionals is obvious as otherwise pretty much by definition there is a maximal ideal $M$ an $\epsilon >0$ and functions $f_k \in M$ for which $|f_k(w)|  >\epsilon$ for all $f_k$ and all $|w|<1$ but then $1$ is in the ideal generated by those so in the maximal ideal contradiction  etc

Comment: The hard part is proving the fact that indeed the infimum positive implies $1$ in the ideal as that proves the Corona  theorem under the form that pointwise  functionals are weakly star dense

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand anything you said. I should not have to use some theorems from some authors, there has to be a simple solution to this by using basic things because it was given as an exercise.

Comment: @Conrad.  I wonder if you are still interested in this question, but I have just proposed an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand\spec{\Delta (H^\infty )}
\newcommand\D{\mathbb D}$ This question has been without an answer for eight months, perhaps due to a comment by user @Conrad  discouraging
pedestrian attempts.  It is true that the Corona Theorem is a very hard problem,   first stated by
Kakutani in 1941 and only settled by Carleson in 1962.  Nevertheless the statement of the question is definitely *not* asking for a
solution of the whole problem, but only for a proof of the equivalence between two well known formulations.

In the hope that there is still interest, here is an answer which is in fact not too hard to give.

---

($\Leftarrow$).  Assuming the condition given, let us prove that $\Delta _0$ is dense in $\spec$.

Arguing by contradiction
suppose that  $\varphi $ is a point of $\spec$ which is not in the closure of $\Delta _0$.  Therefore there exists an open subset
$U\subseteq \spec$ containing  $\varphi $ and which is disjoint from $\Delta_0$.

By the definition of the topology of $\spec$ (pointwise convergence) there are $h_1,h_2,\ldots ,h_n\in H^\infty $, and $\varepsilon >0$, such that
$$
  V:= \{\psi \in \spec: |\psi (h_i)-\varphi (h_i)| <\varepsilon \} \subseteq  U.
  $$

For each $w\in \D$, let $\delta _w$ be the character of $H^\infty $ given by $\delta _w(f)=f(w)$, so $\delta _w$ lies in $\Delta _0$ and consequently
not in $V$.  This implies that there exist some $i$ such that
$$
  |\delta _w(h_i)-\varphi (h_i)| =  |h_i(w)-\varphi (h_i)| \geq \varepsilon .
  $$

For each $j$, let $f_j\in H^\infty $ be defined by $f_j(z)=h_j(z)-\varphi (h_j)$, so the above implies that
$$
  \sum_{j=1}^n |f_j(w)|\geq |f_i(w)|\geq \varepsilon >0.
  $$
Since $w$ is arbitrary we conclude that
$$
  \inf_{z\in \D}\ \sum_{j=1}^n |f_j(z)|\geq \varepsilon >0,
  $$
and hence the hypothesis yields $g_1,g_2,\ldots ,g_n$ in $H^\infty $ such that $\sum_{j=1}^n f_jg_j=1$.  So
$$
  1 = \varphi (1) = \varphi \Big (\sum_{j=1}^n f_jg_j\Big ) = \sum_{j=1}^n \varphi (h_j-\varphi (h_j))\varphi (g_j) =0,
  $$
a contradiction.  This shows that $\Delta _0$ is dense in $\spec$.

($\Rightarrow$).  Assuming that  $\Delta _0$ is dense in $\spec$, let $f_1,f_2,\ldots ,f_n\in H^\infty $ be such that
$$
  \inf_{z\in \D}\
  \sum_{i=1}^n |f_i(z)|>0. \tag{$\dagger$}
  $$
Letting $J$ be the ideal of $H^\infty $ generated by the $f_i$, our goal is to show that $J=H^\infty $.  Again arguing by
contradiction, suppose that $J$ is proper, so Zorn's Lemma implies that there exists a maximal ideal $I\supseteq J$.  By
the Gelfand-Mazur theorem there is $\varphi $ in $\spec$ whose kernel coincides with $I$, and hence $\varphi $ vanishes on all of the
$f_i$'s.

By hypothesis $\varphi $ lies in the closure of $\Delta _0$, so there is a net $\{w_\lambda \}_{\lambda \in \Lambda }$ in $\D$ such that $\delta _{w_\lambda }\to \varphi $.  In
particular this means that, for every $i$, one has that
$$
  0=\varphi (f_i) =
  \lim_\lambda  \delta _{w_\lambda }(f_i) =
  \lim_\lambda  f_i(w_\lambda ),
  $$
hence also
$$
  \lim_\lambda   \sum_{i=1}^n |f_i(w_\lambda )|=0,
  $$
but this contradicts ($\dagger$),  hence showing that $J=H^\infty $, as desired.